# Is it possible to finish Android activities up to a certain number?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I know about this 2 methods in Android and I'd need the "average case method" of them.

finish() is able to finish current activity.

finishAffinity() is able to finish current activity and all of its parent activities.

I'd like a method that is able to finish as many activities as indicated of current activity and some of its parents, for example a made up method like finishCurrentAndParentActivities(2) would finish current activity and its parent, and no more would be finished.

But unfortunately, such a method does not seem to exist and I cannot grasp a good way to achieve such behavior.

What could I do in order to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 2):

You can finish all activities back to a certain known `Activity` in the stack as follows:

```
Intent = new Intent(this, ActivityX.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This code will finish all activities from the top of the stack back to and including the instance of `ActivityX`. It will then create a new instance of `ActivityX` and put that on the top of the stack.

Alternatively you can do this:

```
Intent = new Intent(this, ActivityX.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This code will finish all activities from the top of the stack back to (but excluding) the instance of `ActivityX`. It will not create a new instance of `ActivityX`, but will deliver this `Intent` to the existing instance of `ActivityX` by calling `onNewIntent()`.

These methods are probably more useful than being able to finish some number of activities, since it is difficult to track how many are on the stack that you wish to remove.

However, if you really want to implement something like what you've described, you could do something like this:

- Use a `public static` (global) variable as a counter for how many activities you want to finish
- Set this to the number of activities you want to finish
- Call `finish()` on the current `Activity` and decrement the variable
- In `onResume()` of all of your activities, do the following:

  if (numberOfActivitiesToFinish > 0) {
  numberOfActivitiesToFinish--;
  finish()
  }

As each `Activity` comes to the top of the stack, it will check to see if it should finish, and if so, it decrements the counter and finishes. Not elegant, but does the job.